# ResultSet not positioned properly during entity testing

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, junit

Let's assume I have next two entities:

```
@Entity 
public class Column {
....
}

@Enity
public class Table {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private List<Column> column;
}
```

I have a service class which works with this two entities:

```
@Service
public class JDBCServiceImpl {
  public void writeColToFile(DataSource dataSource, Table table) {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
      int countColumns = table.getColumn.size();
      List<String> columnLst = new ArrayList<>(countColumns);
      for (int i = 0; i < countColumns; i++) {
          columnLst.add(table.getColumn().get(i).getName());
      }
      .........
      ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
      for (int i = 0; i < countColumns; i++) {
           columnFiles[i] = new File(tableDir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" +
           columnLst.get(i) + ".txt"); // here I receive exception
    }
  }
}
```

I also would like to test my service via JUnit.

```
  public class TestService {
      @Test
      public testJDBCService() {
            Column col1 = new Column;
            col1.setName("a");
            ColumnInfo col2 = new ColumnInfo();
            col2.setName("b");
            List<Column> allCols = new ArrayList<>();
            allCols.add(col1);
            allCols.add(col2);
            //
            Table table = new Table();
            table.setName("table1");
            table.setColumn(allCols);
            ...
            jdbcService.writeColToFile(dataSource, table);
      }
    }
```

So when I run my test I receice next exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly,
>   perhaps you need to call next.    at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkResultSet(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2888)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getString(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1963)
>     at
>   service.loader.impl.JDBCServiceImpl.writeColToFile(JDBCServiceImpl.java:73)

From code I see that exception was throw while I try to iterate over List which contain my `column.getName()` object (on this string: `columnLst.get(i)`). So how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this array `columnFiles` wasn't properly initialized, now everything works ok.